# Product of inverse matrix and non-invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Probably an easy question, but can't find anything about it on the internet and it's not in my book.
I know the product of two inverse matrices is an inverse matrix.
Is it possible to get an inverse matrix if you multiply an inverse matrix with a non invertible matrix?
Same with two non-invertible matrices.

Comment: No, since $\text{det}(AB) = \text{det}(A)\text{det}(B)$.

Comment: Presumably, you mean _square_ matrices. For square matrices, how does the determinant relate to invertibility?

Comment: Thanks, the determinant of a non invertible matrix is 0 so because of det(AB)=det(A)det(B) => det(AB)=0

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't seen determinants suppose that $AB$ is invertible. Let $C$ be the inverse of $AB$ then:

\begin{align}
(AB)C = I \\
A(BC) = I
\end{align}

So $A$ is invertible.